# convert hover to click toggle

Tags: javascript, html

i want to convert from hover to mouse click, here's some of the code

HTML

```
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#">Click Me</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linux</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

and here's the script but still in mouseover/mouseleave

```
var dropdown = function() {

    $('.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .find('.dropdown')
            .css('display', 'block')
            .addClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');

    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .find('.dropdown')
            .css('display', 'none')
            .removeClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');
    });

};

dropdown()
```

How can I change this from hover to click?

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to open when clicked and close when clicked outside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.click` with `.toggleClass`

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.has-dropdown')
    .find('.dropdown')
    .css({
      display: function(_, value) {
        return value === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
      }
    })
    .toggleClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-dropdown">
  <a id="toggle" href="#">Click Me</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Linux</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onclick="YourFunction()" and it will execute the function only when you click it.

Not sure if this is what you want, but see this example

*HTML*

```
<input type="button"  value="Click me" onclick="showlist()" />

    <div id="list"  style="display:none;" > 
    
              <ul class="dropdown" type="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Linux</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

*JS*

```
function showlist() {
  var x = document.getElementById("list");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5an2mo0g/4/

Comment: if the function not invoked and using onclick nothing happens, but when invoked already in javascript files the first thing it does is apply the effect when hover, sorry for my bad english

Comment: it still listening on mouseenter/mouseover